# Using API Gateway with CloudFront returning Missing Authentication Token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I've deployed an SPA to S3 Static Hosting. We're using CloudFront in front of it which would be accessed at `www.example.com`

However - we want to be able to trigger a lambda function at `www.example.com/email` as a POST request. I've configured and setup API Gateway and tested both the Lambda function itself, and API Gateway and I am able to send out an email using CURL/Postman.

When trying to use API Gateway through CloudFront I am getting

```json
{
  "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

I've configured a CloudFront origin with API Gateway. It's stage with the **Origin Domain Name** being the API Gateway URL, and the **Origin Path** being the stage (default).

Under behaviours my pattern is `/email*`, with HTTP to HTTPS and allowed HTTP methods is `GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE`.

I've also whitelisted `Authorization` under Whitelist Headers but I am not doing any `Authorization` in my application as of now.

I have also enabled CORS in API Gateway.

Comment: Things to try: http://www.awslessons.com/2017/aws-api-gateway-missing-authentication-token/

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but this message in the response is very misleading. Often it happens because the path doesn't exist and, rather than a `Not Found`, it returns `Missing authentication token`. Did you re-deploy API Gateway after all the changes?

Comment: @E.J.Brennan Unfortunately this does not solve the problem! Thanks though

Comment: @ThalesMinussi I have redeployed after making any changes to API Gateway.

Comment: Just checking if you have the origin path setup as email otherwise the path will change as /email/email and cause "Missing Authentication Token" from API gateway. Pleas ignore if you haven't.

Comment: Do you have enabled API Gateway logs?